# Elasticsearch in Docker on Jenkins fails health check

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, curl, jenkins, docker-compose

I am using Elasticsearch and docker-compose inside a Jenkins pipeline to run my tests. Both Elasticsearch and the Node.js service seem to start properly from Docker, but performing a health check by hitting the `http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health?h=st` endpoint returns status code `000` from `curl`.

Running the tests and performing the health check from inside docker on local (macOS with Docker for Mac) working completely fine, but in Jenkins the health checks fail. Here is what my setup (with error log) looks like:

https://gist.github.com/austinkelleher/ae592eed024328bb738e3bef4dc0af4c

The entry point is `run-tests.sh`

Anypointers would be extraordinarily appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the connection issue by adding `environment: ['transport.host=127.0.0.1'`] to the `elasticsearch` service. See my comment in the gist: https://gist.github.com/austinkelleher/ae592eed024328bb738e3bef4dc0af4c#gistcomment-2591254